# In jedem Schweigen - seine eigene Hysterie

Tags: word-usage, russian-to-german

I want to translate a book's name into German and I want it to be both accurate and natural-sounding. So here is the catch. The book's in Russian and as far as I know it wasn't translated into either English or German. 
So in Russian it goes like this "В каждом молчании своя истерика"(Each silence has its own hysteria).
The closest translations I can come up with are

- In jedem Schweigen - seine (eigene) Hysterie (the literal translation)
- Jedes Schweigen hat seine eigene Hysterie (the problem is, in Russian we don't have auxiliary verbs like to be or to have and I'm trying to avoid them if possible)
- In jeder Stille ihre Hysterie (this one is auto-translated and I strongly believe that the it should be Schweigen unless you prove me wrong)

Thanks in advance!

### Update

Alright, so based on the comments below I feel that I need to add some clarification:

- The book is fictional. Moreover, the reason for asking is my friend wants to make a tattoo with the book's name in German.
- Now that I think about it - we probably need a more poetic translation rather than linguistically accurate

### Second update

Based on further comments and further thinking I narrow the question down to basically 2

1. Stille vs Schweigen vs Sprachlosigkeit?
2. Haben vs Es gibt:
   Jede(s) Stille (Schweigen) hat ihre(seine) Hysterie
   or
   In jeder(m) Stille (Schweigen) gibt es eigene Hysterie?

Comment: Do you want to have an exact translation or a more poetic one, is it to understand the book in a scientific context? What type of book is it? Fictional, Novel? What is the purpose of your translation?

Comment: Hmm. "Stille" seems to fit much more than "Schweigen". You could also use "Sprachlosigkeit". I also have no idea what "Hysterie" is supposed to mean here - It is a neurotic disorder normally connected with everything else but silence... It would be interesting if this is an intended contrast in the Russian title.

Comment: Die Stille (f.), daher "ihre Hysterie".

Comment: @tofro you're absolutely right! The book's title is a kind of oxymoron like 'systematic chaos' etc.

Comment: I' m not sure whether trying to avoid "to be" just because Russian doesn't have it is a reasonable strategy. There is a famous quote from Tolstoy which in German is usually given as „Alle glücklichen Familien gleichen einander, jede unglückliche Familie ist auf ihre eigene Weise unglücklich.“ I don't know the Russian original but I doubt that trying to translate it without the "ist" in the second part gives a satisfactory result.

Comment: @RHa I know this quote and it makes sense! so how would you translate this book's title?

Comment: Here are some suggestions: "Die Hysterie der Stille", "Hinter jedem Schweigen verbirgt sich Hysterie", "Hinter jedem Schweigen steckt Hysterie"

Comment: I am afraid you have to outline the book, I know the Russian soul is really deep reflecting but personally I can not imagine any relation between these two words (even contradictorily) . Also I know Russian to German is really straight to be translated, so I am in doubt it is other than "Schweigen". Why is your friend so eager to have it in German, what is fascinating him/her?

Comment: "Stille" halte ich für keine gute Wahl. Молчание meint, wenn ich das richtig weiß, schon eher das Schweigen (von Menschen oder Lebewesen), nicht die Abwesenheit von Geräusch (Stille).

Comment: @Thomas I can't outline the book as I haven't read it myself. Well, my friend claims she was really influenced by the book and wants its title to be tattooed. If I'm getting her correctly, it doesn't have to be a deeply philosophical translation. At the very least it shouldn't sound as a Google translate. But preferably it should also sound just a bit poetical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ich schlage vor:

> Jedes Schweigen hat etwas Hysterisches

oder

> Jedes Schweigen eine Hysterie

Argumente:

- eingängiger Rhythmus
- *Schweigen* passt besser as *Stille* (молчание ist eher Schweigen als Stille)
- Die zweite Version ist kürzer (gut für einen Buchtitel), aber mir gefällt nicht so gut, dass die Hysterie hier so dominiert, indem sie das Schweigen ganz okkuppiert, während in der ersten Fassung vom Schweigen auch noch was zu hören bleibt, trotz der Hysterie.

Die in der Frage vorgeschlagene Version mit dem Bindestrich geht im Deutschen gar nicht. Solche Bindestreich-Sätze, bei denen das Verb "sein" ausgelassen wird, sind typisch fürs Russische, und russisch Erstsprachsozialisierte übertragen das dann, weil's so praktisch ist, gerne in andere Sprachen, darunter auch Deutsch, aber das deutsche Ohr hört gleich den Russen heraus (oder die Russin).

Der Titel "Jedes Schweigen eine Hysterie" ist im Grunde nicht anders als ein russischer Bindestrich-statt-Verb-Satz, aber man schreibt eben keinen Bindestrich. Das Satzbaumodell an sich ist auch im Deutschen etabliert, z.B.

> Jeder Schuss ein Treffer
>
> Jeder Baum ein kleines Paradies

Answer (score 1):

Well as a student of Philosophy i know the problem with translations, so i recommend you to explain the direkt meanings of the russian title, so we can better understand what does it mean. Like Christian Geiselmann posted :"Stille" isnt a good choice. AFAIK Молчание is the silence of humans, not the silence when there is no sound." Based on this thread i would go for: "Jedes Schweigen zeigt die eigene Hysterie." ("Each silence[=not talking] shows the own hysteria").

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I love to elaborate on this kind of questions and also would like to point out that in share the above-mentioned opinion, that there is no clear cut answer for these, since it is a matter of grasping the underlying philosophical thought. furthermore, since Christian Geiselmann already provided some valuable insight, i would just add a little note to it.

So, after giving it some thought myself i suggest the following, for the adjoining reason:

> Jedem Schweigen wohnt (eine) Hysterie inne or Jeder Stille wohnt (eine) Hysterie inne

--> the word *innewohnen* avoids the ambiguity of using *etwas* or *seine/ihre eigene*, formulas whom don't bespeak the inherent nature of the hysteria, no matter whether it is brought to the silence by ourselves and the outer world contesting it, or whether the silence omits it by itself.

Hope I could help